# Blank space under web page

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a piece of styled-components CSS here. How should I fix it to remove the blank space below the rendered web?

```
const Tetris = () => {

    return (
        <StyledTetrisWrapper>
            <StyledTetris>
                <Stage stage={createStage()} />
                <aside>
                    <div>
                        <Display text="Score" />
                        <Display text="Rows" />
                        <Display text="Level" />
                    </div>
                    <StartButton />
                </aside>
            </StyledTetris>
        </StyledTetrisWrapper>
    )
}


const StyledTetrisWrapper = styled.div`
    background: url(${bgImage2}) #000;
    width: 100 vh;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: cover;
`
```

Image of the error here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJWZj.jpg)

Comment: Maybe change `height: 100vh;`

Comment: You should probably use `width: 100vw;` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const StyledTetrisWrapper = styled.div`
    background: url(${bgImage2}) #000;
    width: 100vw;
    height:100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    `
```

I added background-size cover and height 100vh;

Comment: You should probably only have one height assignement in that style, one of them is getting overwritten anyway.

Comment: Oh yeah i didnt see the one that he already had. Thanks for pointing out. @NilsKähler